# How to determine the sequence of functions used?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm currently writing a program for a 3-number gym dial lock. The way a real-life dial works is you must turn right to the first number, turn left to the second  number, and turn right again to the third number. I have functions that look like turnRight and turnLeft.
Currently I'm writing tests for my combo lock and one test involves turning to the right numbers but in the wrong directions (right, right, right, instead of right, left, right). Is there a way to determine the sequence in which functions were used (ex. turnRight, turnLeft, turnRight was used so return 1)?

Thank You

Comment: There is a way to go with the global std::list<std::string> variable where you can store the function names called but its not recommended. You need to check what function does and based on the return value you need to verify if the called sequence is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

one way is

```
     enum {RIGHT, LEFT};

     int my_combo[]=
     {
       RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT, -1 ///-1 is a delimiter in order to test if the end of the array of combo keys.
     };

     TypeReturn turnLeft(){...}
     TypeReturn turnRight(){...}

     ...
     ///the function where you are going to test it, for this example return Boolean
     /// you change for your need

     int entry_combo[]={RIGHT, RIGHT, RIGHT, -1};
     /// this could be a while loop too, some people preferred that
      bool ret = true;
     int i(0);
     for(; ;i++)
     {
        if(entry_combo[i]!= -1 && my_combo[i] !=-1)
        {
            if(entry_combo[i] != my_combo[i])
               { 
                  ret = false;
                  break;
                }
             else
               {
                     ////here you could put turnLeft or turnRight, depending of what value are in my_combo.
               }
        }
        else
        {
            ret = (i==0)?true:(entry_combo[i] != my_combo[i])?false:ret))      ; /// you must decide if what to return if the combo key  
                                    /// are empty. for me just return true. there are other criteria to choose,
        }
     } 
 return ret;
```